# Scrolling RTL UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, right-to-left

I've the following code in `viewDidLoad`.

```
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            collectionView.semanticContentAttribute = .ForceRightToLeft
        }
```

Then, when I try to scroll to an index path in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath,
                                                atScrollPosition: .CenteredHorizontally,
                                                animated: false)
```

It doesn't work. but when I change ForceRightToLeft and make it ForceLeftToRight. It works.

Comment: Can you attach a sample project at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)?

Comment: Yes, I think I should do that.

Comment: Thanks for doing this :)

Comment: It seems I'm wrong. Sorry about that. While trying to do an example project. I figured out that there was a problem with the indices in my code. Now the scrolling works for RTL. Thank you so much

Comment: Ah, that's good to hear!